# How do we prove that $|\mathbb{P}(X = m) - \mathbb{P}(Y = m)| \leq \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y )$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

While preparing for an upcoming test in probability, I ran into the following question.

Let $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X,Y :\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Prove that for every $m\in\mathbb{R}$, it holds that

$$|\mathbb{P}(X = m) - \mathbb{P}(Y = m)| \leq \mathbb{P}(X \neq Y )$$

I'm not sure about the meaning of $X \neq Y$. My intuition tells me that its something like $\forall \omega \in \Omega \;, Y(\omega) \ne X(\omega)$.

Is this right?

Comment: It means exactly that, you are correct

Comment: m-m would always give zero, so how does one make zero always less than or equal to when two variables don't match?  It would mean that X would always need to be greater than Y, and that P(X-Y).

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X\ne Y)$ is a short way to write $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega)\ne Y(\omega)\})$. In English: if you pick $\omega\in\Omega$, this is the probability that $X(\omega)\ne Y(\omega)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your terminology question: $P(X \neq Y) = P(\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \neq Y(\omega) \})$, as stated in the comments.

For the other question, in fact, more is true. For any measurable set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have:
\begin{align*}
    P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A) &= P(X \in A) - [ P(Y \in A, X \in A) + P(Y \in A, X \not\in A) ] \\
    &\leq P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A, X \in A) \\
    &= P(X \in A, Y \not\in A) \\
    &\leq P(X \neq Y)
\end{align*}
You may argue similarly for $P(Y \in A) - P(X \in A)$, so that you can put an absolute value on the left-hand side.
If you set $A = \{m\}$ you then specialise to your case.